# eclipse console text colors

Tags: eclipse, colors, console

I need that change that blue.  When it's high noon and the sun is a the azimuth, I have to get super close to read the letters.  Can something be done?
[image: console image]

Comment: Even though the blue does not quite look like the same color, I would think that is the `Standard in text color` value?

Comment: Do ou know where I can change the standard in text color value, I googled it byut can't find it, If you meant the light blue one, that's not it.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the light blue one (below the `Standard Error text color`) ... but that's not the one, correct?

Comment: I have to wait until I have the opportunity to try again because I rarely use the console, I do most of my debugging with the jupiter notebooks.  Too bad we can't make that a different color scheme

Comment: None oh these color settings change that dark blue. I ended changing the background

Answer (score 9):

If you are using PyDev, go to window -> preferences -> PyDev -> interactive console. You'll find the "Stdin color", that's the one!

[image: eclipse interactive console preferences]

Answer (score 4):

For C/C++ Build Console, it can be done by following this menu:

```
Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Build > Console
```

Then, you can change colors to what you want.

Answer (score 3):

just go to Window -> preferences -> Run/Debug -> console
then set Standard Error Text Color as your one
and thats all